# complex query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables like this:

```
table a:

    [id, name, roll, address, mark]

table b

    [id, name, fee, reg_date]
```

now I'm running a query like this:

```
select * from a, b where a.id = b.id;
```

and I'm using 'mysql_fetch_object' .
Now how can I print name of table a and name of table b??

I tried this:

```
class foo {
    public $name;
}

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("dodex");

$result = mysql_query("select * from a, b where a.id = b.id");
$obj = mysql_fetch_object($result, 'foo');
var_dump($obj);
```

to find a way, but I can't.

Comment: What is your question, what doesn't work? What errors do you get?

Comment: The name of the table? Or the value of the name column from the table? For the second: `select a.name, b.name from a, b where a.id = b.id`

Comment: I want to get a.name and b.name

Comment: I used $row->a.name but this doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mysql_fetch_assoc`, instead of `mysql_fetch_object`:

```
$a = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $a['a.name'];
echo $a['b.name'];
```

Otherwise, with `mysql_fetch_object`, you can do this:

```
$obj = mysql_fetch_object($result,'foo');
echo $obj->{'a.name'};
echo $obj->{'b.name'};
```

Answer (score 2):

using `select *` is usually a bad idea (this is one reason why).

You should declare each field you're looking for, which then allows you to alias them for clarity:

```
select a.id as id, a.name as aName, b.name as bName, roll, address, mark, fee, reg_date
from a, b 
where a.id = b.id;
```

also, consider explicit join - it makes things easier to debug at least (in my experience):

```
select a.id as id, a.name as aName, b.name as bName, roll, address, mark, fee, reg_date
from a
join b on a.id=b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use aliases in your SQL if the tables have columns that share the same name. Otherwise, you can't access the properties by name because they get overwritten.